# Issue in text-to-speech iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am using speech-to-text and text-to-speech in my application. The problem is when search through voice from speech-to-text, the code is working fine but when I want my device should revert back of my action through text-to-speech, it is producing error and the error is :-

> Failure starting audio queue ≥˚˛ˇ
>
> _BeginSpeaking: couldn't begin playback

I am using this function as delay. After given delay the webService would hit. But it is producing error.

```
func delayValue(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->())

 {
        
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
       
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)

 }
```

So please help me to get-out of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please anyOne of you help me ?